# Книги по искусственному интеллекту

Tags: книги, искусственный-интеллект

Что читали и можете посоветовать по ИИ (искусственный интеллект)? Интересует как и общие сведения, так и именно разработка ИИ для игровых проектов. Для начала хотелось бы узнать, что можно почитать на русском, но так же рассмотрю варианты англоязычных книг. Бумажный вариант даже приятнее, если он есть в продаже.

Comment: Здесь приведена хорошая библиография: [искусственный интеллект][1], со ссылками на Озон.


  [1]: http://pmg.org.ru/ai/index.html

Comment: С. Хайкин Нейронные сети полный курс

Answer (score 8):

Я  пока что не прочел ни одной книжки по ИИ (как академическом, так и игровом), но думаю, это будет полезно:

> Для начала хотелось бы узнать, что можно почитать на русском

Забудьте о существовании русского языка применительно к изучению ИИ. Вспоминать о нем можно, задавая вопросы на [gamedev.ru](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?ai).

Литература, полезные ссылки:

*Академический ИИ*

- [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=AI&x=0&y=0#/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_6?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=artificial+intelligence&sprefix=Artifi%2Cstripbooks%2C259&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Aartificial+intelligence) - открыв ссылку на любую книгу, в конце странички можно увидеть рецензии людей, купивших книгу и соотношение +/-.
- [Stanford AI](https://www.ai-class.com/home/) - cовсем недавно прошел бесплатный видеокурс от Стенфорда, видео доступны на youtube (по ссылке оглавление слева). Насколько я понимаю, книга, по которой они идут: [AI modern approach](http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Modern-Approach-3rd/dp/0136042597/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1327171436&sr=1-1). (Кстати, насчет бесплатных курсов Стэнфорда: скоро они запускают новый цикл курс (AI в нем не будет), идет запись желающих, например - [Design and Analysis of Algorithms I](http://www.algo-class.org/), остальные курсы в конце странички)

*Игровой ИИ*

- [Полезные ссылки](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/592473-recommended-ai-books-and-sites/) - автор поста сам написал [книгу](http://www.amazon.com/Behavioral-Mathematics-Game-Dave-Mark/dp/1584506849/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1327171361&sr=1-6), в его компетенции можно не сомневаться.
- [Programming Game AI by Example](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Game-Example-Mat-Buckland/dp/1556220782/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1327171361&sr=1-3) - действительно хороша, к ней приложены очень интересные примеры программ на С++ с исходным кодом.
- [Gamedev.net AI](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/9-artificial-intelligence/) - если возникают вопросы в процессе обучения, то стоит писать туда.

Answer (score 1):

Советую ознакомиться с материалами на этом [сайте](http://intelligence.org/). Вообще, эта организация занимается разработкой, исследованием и оценкой рисков, связанных со сверхчеловеческим искусственным интеллектом.

Также стоит ознакомиться со [статьями](http://yudkowsky.net/singularity) одного из участников этого проекта. Если есть желание, то к этому проекту можно и присоединиться, но для этого нужно иметь очень много нетривиальных знаний.